# Selectively override Easy Digital Downloads protection via filter

Tags: plugins, filters

I am working on a Patreon integration for my Wordpress site which uses Easy Digital Downloads to paywall downloadable products. Patreon members access the site via oauth, and I would like them to have full access to all downloads. Finding the hook(s) to make this possible has been a challenge.

The site uses the EDD All Access Pass extension, and I've managed to disable that via this hook:

```
add_filter( 'edd_all_access_allow', '__return_false', 20, 1 );
```

A filter search in the EDD plugin directory, however, lists hundreds of filters, which I'm sorting through, but as of yet I've had no luck finding a suitable hook to selectively disable download protection.

Any guidance is appreciated.

[EDIT] I am realizing that achieving this is absuredly complicated, if practically impossible. There should be a built-in way to programmatically bypass various kinds of checks, such as payment, customer, etc. I don't anticipate any answers to this question, but will certainly post my solution if I ever avail one.

Comment: I think you're going to have to ask Easy Digital Downloads directly sorry. They'll know their code better than we do.

Comment: Otherwise I'd try debugging a download and see where you get stuck. That probably won't be easy / fun though, I've had to pick through Gravity Forms in the past and it was somewhat more complicated than it needed to be :-/

Comment: @Rup I appreciate the guidance. Taking a break to hopefully tackle with a fresh perspective then do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that it cannot be done in any practical manner. Easy Digital Downloads presents layer after layer of internal auditing to ensure that downloads are protected and that the protection is not easily circumvented. The plugin vendor cannot be faulted for this inconvenience.

There is a better solution, however, and it lies with an EDD extension called EDD All-Access. Adding an order programmatically, for example via `edd_insert_payment()`, with a product that is designated as an All-Access product solves the problem of granting free access to all or select downloads.